# ForEach Character in String

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, how do you loop through each character in a string using ForEach?

For example

```
let some_string = "A⍺甲あ"

VStack {
  ForEach(....) {....
    Text(String(character_in_the_string))
  }
}
```

Output

```
A
⍺
甲
あ
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ForEach` requires that the value passed to it conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`.  A `String` is a `Sequence`, and it can be turned into a `RandomAccessCollection` by making it into an `Array`.

Use `Array()` to turn the string into `[Character]`:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(Array(some_string), id: \.self) { character in
        Text(String(character))
    }
}
```

---

In general, you should be careful to choose an `id` that is unique.  Since `some_string` could contain repeated characters, you could instead use `.enumerated()` to turn each `Character` into an `(offset, element)` pair (where `offset` is its position in the `String`). Then use `.offset` as the `id` and `.element` to retrieve the `Character` from the tuple pair:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(Array(some_string.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { character in
        Text(String(character.element))
    }
}
```

This would matter, for instance, if you were animating the removal of characters from the string.  If you use the character as the `.id`, SwiftUI may choose the wrong character to animate if several of the same character are listed in a row.

Answer (score 1):

```
let yourString = Array("A⍺甲あ") // convert your string to an array

VStack {
    ForEach(0..<yourString.count) { num in
        Text(String(yourString[num]))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A 
⍺ 
甲 
あ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach(Array(mystring.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index,character in
    Text(String(character))
        .font(.system(size: 20))
}
```